# Is there a way to solve this recurring function using dynamic programming?

Tags: c#

I have this recurring function and I need to write it using dynamic programming. The problem is that it returns double, not int and I can't change that. If it was returning integer, I could store returned value at corresponding index in array and later use it to find other values.

```
static double f(double n)
{
    if(n > 1)
    {
        return f(n - 3) + (9 * (f(n / 5) * f(n / 5))) + (2 * f(n - 7))
              + ((n * n * n * n) / 2);
    }
    else
    {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

For example if n=1 I know that result is 4 so I can store ir as `data[1]=4;` but when I geto to n=6 this doesn't work because 6/5 = 1.2 and I don't know what functions result of 1.2 is and I could not store it using array. I could use dictionary to store key-value pair, but then again, I wouldn't know what result is of 1.2.

Comment: whats 'dynamic programming' in this context?

Comment: I suspect you are talking about [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)...

Comment: Using known data to find next value

Comment: Wait, why can't you use a dictionary? `Dictionary<double, double>` could store a double key (`1.2`) and a double value (`f(1.2)`)

Comment: I could store that, but first of all I need to calculate functions value of 1.2 using data I already know, and I don't know if it's even possible

Comment: You can't use predictive programming with a double, (you can but it's implractical), with integers you will limit values to increment one by one, so you can compute the values between a min and a max, but with double values you should compute in values which increment by double.Epsilon, that will create a tremendous amount of data just for values between 1 & 2. So, the best you can do is to cache results like Rufus posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use a `Dictionary<double,double>` to store the results:

```
private static Dictionary<double, double> results = new Dictionary<double, double>();

private static double f(double n)
{
    if (results.ContainsKey(n)) return results[n];

    double result = (n > 1)
        ? f(n - 3) + (9 * (f(n / 5) * f(n / 5))) +
          (2 * f(n - 7)) + ((n * n * n * n) / 2)
        : 4;

    results.Add(n, result);
    return result;
}
```